# Mac mini with an iPad as the only display?

Tags: macos, ipad, sidecar

Can I run a Mac mini with an iPad as the only display?

Let's say that Sidecar has some kind of an autostart and when the Mac mini boots, it automatically gets started.

Answer (score 4):

Sidecar lets you use an iPad as a secondary display for your Mac. So Sidecar doesn't have any such kind of mode that lets you use an iPad as the only display.

You can, however, explore some 3rd party solutions which claim to make your iPad usable as a standalone display for a Mac mini. A such prominent 3rd party solution is Luna Display, Headless Mode

- https://shop.astropad.com/pages/headless-mode

> With Luna Display, turn your iPad into the primary display for Mac mini. Combine the best of Mac mini and iPad by harnessing the processing power of the Mac mini and the edge-to-edge full display of the iPad.
>
> #### Minimum Requirements
>
> - Mac mini must be a 2011 model or later, and running macOS 10.11 (El Capitan) or later
> - iPad must be an iPad 2, iPad Mini, iPad Pro, or iPad Air model running iOS 9.1 or later (32-bit devices are not supported)
>   External mouse and keyboard connected to Mac mini are optimal for this setup in case of MacOS permissions and logins
>
> #### How to Get Started
>
> 1. **An external display is required to get set up**, but is only needed the first time you configure your devices (unless FileVault is enabled).
> 2. Luna Display requires a Mac application to run. For Headless Mode, if FileVault is in use, an external display will be needed to unlock your drive whenever you reboot.

- https://help.astropad.com/article/218-how-do-i-use-luna-display-in-headless-mode

> [image]
>
> ### Headless Mode: Using your iPad as the display for Mac mini
>
> #### What you will need to get started:
>
> - Mac Mini
> - iPad
> - Luna Display and latest versions of the Luna Display apps, available for download at [lunadisplay.com/hello](http://www.lunadisplay.com/hello)
>
> Reliable local WiFi network connection or USB cable
>
> **We recommend connecting an external keyboard to your Mac mini.**

---

**P.S.**: No affiliation whatsoever with Luna Display or any subsidiaries. Never used it personally before.

Answer (score 0):

My ugly work around, for now...

Log in to Mac mini m1 from iPad using VNC free.

Go to preferences and activate sidecar and connect back to the iPad then close vnc.

It's a bit clumsy but once sidecar is activated you can switch back and forward between car and sidecar session fairly easily and consistently.

It would be great to be able to do all that with a script, but I'm not expert enough to do it...

Mac mini doesn't have great bluetooth (even typing this now, the mouse hung up for a few seconds) TBH, so a limitation is is you have to be near it to use peripherals. So, when I work with it, I keep the iPad 'tethered' anyway. This way works (almost) flawlessly :)

I'm using an old iPad pro and new Mac mini M1 basically because my old MacBook Air is dying and I can't afford to replace everything right now. It was a good solution as most of my work now is stationary. Its not a perfect laptop replacement, obvs, and its not a perfect desktop replacement, but it's pretty good.

Thanks, Jeff